# Exclude indentation characters from a split() using jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm a beginner in jQuery and JavaScript world.

I want a simply way to just ignore all character indentation from a split().

HTML (lorem with 20 words)-

```
<p style="text-align: center">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequuntur esse illo iusto laudantium maxime nostrum
    quidem repellendus sunt! Eaque, voluptatibus.
</p>
```

jQuery -

```
var splitWords = $("p").text().split(" ")
console.log(splitWords)
```

Output -

```
(27) ["↵", "", "", "", "Lorem", "ipsum", "dolor", "sit", "amet,", "consectetur", "adipisicing", "elit.", "Cumque", "esse", "odio", "praesentium", "provident", "quas", "repellendus↵", "", "", "", "voluptatem", "voluptates.", "Enim,", "exercitationem,", "quasi!↵"]
```

The output should be a array with 20 words but its including the indentation characters, how can I exclude them ? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could split by a regular expression of any whitespace instead:

```
$("p").text().split(/\s+/)
```

(`\s` will match normal spaces, tab characters, and other whitespace characters)

Or match non-space characters:

```
$("p").text().match(/\S+/g)
```

Comment: A doubt: \S take a non-space character, in mine HTML example will be the "L" right ? Why "+" is taking all word ?

Comment: `\S` matches a non-space character. Put `+` after a token to repeat it. `+` means "match one or more of the preceding token". So `\S+` means "match one or more non-space characters".